# Getting the full file path when using a file upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I wrote some code to upload files to amazon S3, if I put a full file path manually It successfully uploads the file from my computer. What I'm trying to do is use a file upload control and store the full path in a variable so that I can use it for my amazon method. Ive read everywhere it seems that the browser won't let you get the full file path for security reasons.

How can I get the full file path? Should I just store the files on my webserver and point my amazon method to the server path, and then use the file upload control to tell it what the filename is? I wish I could just do a straight shot to amazon...

Comment: you can never get the path from the clients browser... but i fail to see how that can be in ANY way relevant. You get the filename, so just construct the full path your self. Ie. put all uploaded files in one predefined folder.

Comment: @Andrew Barber, Apology accepted.

Comment: @Pauli, I was trying to not save the file to my webserver then construct the absolute path. I was trying to take it straight from the client to amazon. Unfortunately, the amazon api asks for a abs path. I guess I will have to save the file to my webserver. No big deal I guess.

Comment: why would you need to save it on the webserver!? if its because the amazon api requires a file path to read from when uploading im sure there is an overload taking a stream as well!

Comment: @Pauli, The SDK for this is not good, they show you how to create objects(files with nothing in them, which there is no real world reason why you would want to do this),but not how to upload a real file, I had to poke around and figure it out on my own to get as far as I have already.

Comment: When uploading a file to asp.net it will always be saved on your webserver, normally under some temp-directory before you normally would save it to a location of your own preference. Unfortunately you can't get the path to that, so the only way is to save the file via HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(string), pass that path to Amazon and delete the file afterwards. If there is a overload accepting a stream you can pass HttpPostedFile.InputStream to Amazon and skip saving the file.

Comment: @Pauli, It does have a inputstream property, but I don't know what to use as a parameter(it takes one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this link which has a great tutorial and even gives you a working sample project. (this is different from the code that the .net SDK includes...) http://aws.amazon.com/articles/774?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Answer (score 1):

First we have to save the file path and then we take it from

```
string filepath=Path.GetFullPath(UploadFile1.FileName.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't take full path in HTML or JS as it violets security so whenever you try to see the path it shows fakepath

so to resolve this issue you can make a seprate folder and you can store the uploaded file there and in the code you can take that folders path as default and use it as a absolute path.

You can get the full path using Python Tkinter but it is limited for desktop app.